# How to convert JsonForm to Json?

Tags: java, json, jsonforms

I would like to extract only the data present in a Json to JsonForm using Java.

Which framework can I use to this operation?

Comment: Could you precise what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to create a form using a json created in java?
Or are you trying to retrieve data from a submitted form?

Comment: I want to retrieve the data from JsonForm in Json format using a java framework.

Comment: If you have no framework at all, any java web framework could do. See a few here : https://dzone.com/articles/most-popular-java-web-frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Don't let the ugly aspect of JsonForm deceive you. I don't know if this apply for all cases, but I just had to extract the Json object that contains only the data. This can be done using any common Json parser, as like as Gson.